# Regex: last occurrence of character before

Tags: regex

In this comma delimited text I want to capture just the parts with 'match' in between, and the commas on either side

```
text,something,hello,house,ymatchy,motor,xmatchx,yoyo
```

Currently I've got

```
,.*?match.*?,
```

However it matches

```
[1] ,something,hello,house,ymatchy,
[2] ,xmatchx,
```

I only want the first match the comma directly before the text, not from the beginning - I just want **,ymatchy,**

***Edit:***

Also how would it work if I was matching multiple characters, say the url encoding equivalent of a comma (%2C)

```
text%2Csomething%2Cmatch%2Chello%2Chouse%2Cy%2match%2y%2Cmotor%2Cxmatchx%2Cyoyo
```

I would want to match

```
[1] %2Cmatch%2C
[2] %2Cy%2match%2y%2C
[3] %2Cxmatchx%2C
```

Comment: In what language is the regex implementation?

Comment: @Jerry it's not really for anything, just for learning

Comment: And what if the language you want to use doesn't support negative lookaheads?

Comment: @Jerry considering this was an abstract task I don't think that's a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below regex,

```
,[^,]*match[^,]*,
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cP9kE6/1)

If you want `,ymatchy,` then remove the global flag.

Update:

```
%2C\w+match\w+%2C
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cP9kE6/2)

Comment: Thanks for this, I updated my question with a part on multiple characters as the delimiters, do you know how it would work in that scenario?

Comment: @SomeGuy updated my answer. Let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: I updated my question with some non-word characters (% etc etc) and also added one with no excess characters on either side of 'match'

Comment: Sorry for all the back and forth, I updated it one last time I hope, I put a non-word character before the 'match' word in the 2nd example, it should be able to match anything to the left and right of 'match' as long as it's in the middle of two %2C instances

Comment: you mean the first and last would be `%2C` and in the middle there is a string `match`.Am i correct?

Comment: %2C {any thats not "%2C"} match {any thats not "%2C"} %2C (ignore spaces)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my 2nd half

```
%2C((?!%2C).)*match((?!%2C).)*%2C
```

I've marked Avinash Raj's answer as accepted, as he answered my original question.

Comment: How about this [`(%2C)(?:(?!\1).)*match(?:(?!\1).)*\1`](http://regex101.com/r/zZ8vG3/3)?

Comment: @AvinashRaj that's also nice, not having to repeat code :)